# Explain curious behavior of Pandas.Series.interpolate

Tags: pandas, numpy, scipy, interpolation

```
s = pd.Series([0, 2, np.nan, 8])
print(s)

interp = s.interpolate(method='polynomial', order=2)
print(interp)
```

This prints:

```
0    0.0
1    2.0
2    NaN
3    8.0
dtype: float64
0    0.000000
1    2.000000
2    4.666667
3    8.000000
dtype: float64
```

Now if I add one more `np.nan` to the `series`,

```
s = pd.Series([0, 2, np.nan, np.nan, 8])
print(s)

interp = s.interpolate(method='polynomial', order=2)
print(interp)
```

I get much more accurate results:

```
0    0.0
1    2.0
2    NaN
3    NaN
4    8.0
dtype: float64
0    0.0
1    2.0
2    4.0
3    6.0
4    8.0
dtype: float64
```

Is `Series.interpolate` `recursive` in that it uses interpolated values for further interpolated values, which then can affect previously interpolated values?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**You are actually interpolating two different functions!**

In the first case you look for a function that goes thorugh the following points: 
(0,0),  (1,2),  (**3**,8) 
But in the second case you look for a function that goes through the following points: 
(0,0),   (1,2),   (**4**,8)

The indices of a `pd.Series` represent the points on the x-Axis and the data of a `pd.Series` represents the points on the y-Axis.

So try the following change in your first example:

<s>`s = pd.Series([0, 2, np.nan, 8])`</s>

```
s = pd.Series([0, 2, np.nan, 8], [0,1,2,4])
s.interpolate(method='polynomial', order=2)
```

You should get the output:

```
0    0.0
1    2.0
2    4.0
4    8.0
dtype: float64
```

As an alternative you could also do:
`s = pd.Series([0, 2, np.nan, 8], [0,1,3,4])`

 and the output:

```
0    0.0
1    2.0
3    6.0
4    8.0
dtype: float64
```

Hope this helps.